# Why did Democrats on the House Rules Committee vote against the debt ceiling bill?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, democratic-party

Yesterday the House Rules Committee advanced a bill to raise the debt ceiling, but with no Democratic support. [From the New York Post](https://nypost.com/2023/05/30/house-rules-committee-narrowly-advances-bill-to-raise-debt-ceiling/):

> The GOP-controlled committee voted 7-6 to move the 99-page piece of legislation to the House floor, with no Democrats joining Republicans in support.

All reports I've read seem to indicate that with McCarthy and Biden coming to an agreement, the mainstream members of each party will support the bill when it comes to a vote on the floor. Later in the same article Hakeem Jeffries, the House Minority Leader, heavily implies that the Democrats will vote for the bill.

> House Minority Leader Hakeem Jeffries (D-NY) told reporters Tuesday that “Democrats are committed to making sure we do our part in avoiding default.” “My expectation is House Republicans will keep their commitment to produce at least two-thirds of their conference which is approximately 150 votes,” he said.

Why then would the Democrats in the House Rules committee not vote to advance the bill to the floor? If one more Republican had voted against it then the Democrats could have easily been blamed for the fallout if it didn't advance, which seems a large risk for a bill that the party intends to support on the floor.

Edited to add: Even more interestingly, three of the four Democratic HR Committee members (Scanlon, Neguse, and Fernandez) voted NO in committee but AYE on the floor.

Comment: Progressives consider the compromises [not progressive enough](https://www.axios.com/2023/05/30/progressives-debt-ceiling-deal-vote).  The clue might be in the particular leanings and affiliations of the [Dems on that committee](https://rules.house.gov/about/rules-committee-members).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica You're right that all of the Dems on the HR Committee are a part of the Progressive Caucus. I didn't realize it was so large - almost half of sitting House Dems! Does this mean that the debt ceiling bill passing on the floor is not as certain as it seemed?

Comment: I didn't know they were all Progs.  Ah, well, if you link to where you found their affiliation to the Progs, then you could post that as a self-answer.  Not impressed with *this* lot, looking quite as clueless as the Gaetzes of this world, playing games for partisan reasons.  I dunno about wider vote, but there's *probably* enough common sense members on both sides to see it through, putting all Progs on the Dem side of an important committee was a tactical mistake by Dem leadership, IMHO.

Comment: @DavidK No one is sure that this is a "done deal". There are far-right conservatives who think it's a disaster that the bill doesn't have a specific debt limit, just a time limit. And there are progressives who think that Biden made too many concessions. And the general Dem belief was that there shouldn't be any conditions at all. Neither side really expected that the result of the negotiation would just be rubber-stamped.

Comment: FWIW, the New York Post may not make for the [most reliable of sources](https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/%20new%20york%20post/), though in this case they got it right.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I actually started with BBC, but NYP happened to have more concise quotable statements.

Comment: Re *If one Republican had voted against it then the Democrats ...* Two Republicans did vote with the Democrats in opposition of moving the bill forward. The vote in the Rules Committee was 7-6 rather than 9-4, which is what it would have been had all Republican members voted in favor and all Democratic members voted against.

Comment: @DavidHammen Good catch. Edited to say "one more", though it does lessen the impact of the statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 4 Dems on this [House Committee](https://rules.house.gov/about/rules-committee-members).  They are **all** [members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_Congressional_Progressive_Caucus) of  the [Progressive Caucus](https://progressives.house.gov) .

[Ranking Member Jim McGovern (D-MA)](https://mcgovern.house.gov)
Rep. Mary Gay Scanlon (D-PA)
Rep. Joe Neguse (D-CO)
Rep. Teresa Leger Fernández(D-NM)

Now, as I said before, the Progressives object to [negotiating with the Republicans and cutting some of their preferred programs](https://www.axios.com/2023/05/30/progressives-debt-ceiling-deal-vote).

> She cited the bill's welfare work requirements and energy permitting reforms as examples of provisions progressives are displeased with.
> "There will be real harmful impacts for poor people and working people," she said, adding that members have “serious concerns about the environmental justice implications of this bill."

But it might be even more instructive to see what the lead Dem Committee member, [McGovern had to say](https://mcgovern.house.gov/news/documentsingle.aspx?DocumentID=400004):

> WASHINGTON—Today, Congressman James P. McGovern, Ranking Member of the House Rules Committee, slammed the GOP for lying about SNAP work requirements during the Republican debt crisis negotiations so they can go after food assistance programs that working families rely on.
>
> “Maybe if [Speaker Kevin McCarthy] weren’t so busy giving speeches to Wall Street bankers, he’d know most people on food assistance are children, seniors, or people with disabilities,” said Congressman McGovern on the House Floor. “Maybe if he spoke to an able-bodied adult on food assistance, he’d know they aren’t sitting on the couch because they’re out working—they just make so little they qualify for a measly six-dollar-a-day benefit they use to buy food.

Now, unlike the other answer, I believe they are playing with fire wrt public opinion.  In the past government shutdowns, the Reps have generally loaded the gun *and* pulled the trigger.  I.e. they manufactured the crisis and were too intransigent to avoid a shutdown.  For which they got blamed by Jane Public.

This time the Reps have loaded the gun, but if the deal goes South due to the Progressives, they will have pulled the trigger, not the Republicans.

The public, once it wakes up to another government shutdown, will look to who was the **last** group involved.  Not negotiating, as Biden started out to do?  The Dems.  Scuppering it, via the behavior asked about in this Q?  The Dems.

Some observations:

- The US debt ceiling is, as it exists, a pretty silly system.  The time to worry about debt is when you pass a budget.
- 2/3 of Fed expenditures are entitlement, by law:  pensions, Medicare/aid.  Off-budget, essentially.  Of the rest 1/6 is Defense, 1/6 non-Defense, things like education and welfare.
- So the Reps, after never cutting spending, but cutting taxes (Trump 2017, heavily warned by CBO as a deficit bomb) act as if they had nothing to with it, want to ring-fence Defense and want to concentrate all the cuts on the remaining 1/6th.
- Nevertheless the US is living above its means and needs to get a grip.  Supposedly the unhappy compromise here is rated [$1.5T by CBO](https://www.npr.org/2023/05/31/1178995328/debt-ceiling-cbo-house-vote-mccarthy-biden-spending-deficit).  A trillion here, a trillion there, pretty soon you're talking real money.

> Most of the estimated reduction in the deficit from the deal would come from caps on discretionary spending other than defense — a relatively small slice of the overall federal budget
>
> The agreement adds new work requirements for older people receiving food stamps, but also adds new exemptions from work requirements for veterans, people experiencing homelessness and young people recently out of foster care.
>
> CBO projects the number of people made eligible for food stamps by the new exemptions would outweigh the number who might be dropped from the rolls.

Still, among the dumb, Rep-insisted things in that compromise:

> A plan to cut $1.4 billion in spending on the Internal Revenue Service, for example, would reduce tax collections by an estimated $2.3 billion — for a net loss to the government of $900 million.
>
> The actual loss in tax revenue could be much larger, since the Biden administration is planning to "repurpose" another $20 billion of the $80 billion that had been set aside for the IRS as part of the Inflation Reduction Act.

If I understand correctly, this cut will allow safer tax evasion for tax shirkers.

So, no, not a great compromise and, no not driven by sane budgeting either.  But still an irresponsible move by the Progressive members, albeit for much nobler reasons than the [Freedom Caucus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Caucus) on the even more daft opposite side.

Apparently the [thought of the more mainstream folk](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/congress/live-blog/debt-ceiling-vote-live-updates-house-will-take-biden-mccarthy-plan-ton-rcna86870) as well:

> The House voted to pass Speaker Kevin McCarthy's debt ceiling deal with President Joe Biden tonight on a **314-117 vote**.

[CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2023/05/31/politics/house-vote-debt-limit-bill/index.html)

> The final tally for the vote was 314 to 117. **There were 149 Republicans and 165 Democrats who voted for the bill and 71 Republicans and 46 Democrats who voted against it.**
>
> Suspending the debt limit through 2025 takes the threat of default off table until after the presidential election. In addition to addressing the debt limit, the bill caps non-defense spending, expands work requirements for some food stamp recipients and claws back some Covid-19 relief funds, among other policy provisions.

p.s. In addition to all that, this rejection by *some* members of his own party makes Biden look weak.  They'd be better served working behind the scenes trying to convince him to let someone else run in 2024.

Comment: Whenever only one side compromises you lock yourself into a position of weakness. This is the stance of the progressive caucus. That Dems have lost control even while in power because they feel (rightly or wrongly) only their side compromises under these sorts of pressures.

Comment: Interestingly, three of the four Dem HR Committee members (Scanlon, Neguse, and Fernandez) voted no in committee but yes on the floor.

Comment: With regard to *this rejection by some members of his own party makes Biden look weak.* I disagree. More than half of the Progressive Caucus (which has a history of disliking Biden) voted for the bill. On the other hand, the significantly larger number of Republican votes against the bill make McCarthy look weak.

Comment: "The time to worry about debt is when you pass a budget." Theoretically true, but this assumes you actually are passing a budget rather than some last-minute CRs that no one has time to debate, amend, or, in many cases, even read or understand. At least one good thing about the compromise bill is that it requires those budget bills to actually be passed or else automatic cuts take place that neither side want.

Comment: *A plan to cut $1.4 billion in spending on the Internal Revenue Service, for example, would reduce tax collections by an estimated $2.3 billion* => the effectiveness of the IRS diminishes for every additional dollar spent, rather than staying constant, so these numbers should be taken with a grain of salt. I.e. as an extreme example, spending an extra $1T on the IRS per year won't net the US government an extra $1.5T in revenue.

Comment: @Jontia You're not wrong, *assuming the action stops at the negotiation round*, like it often does in other contexts.  It doesn't in this scenario: the final, and most weighty, event is who gets blamed by the *electorate*.  Not the *pundits, not the "base", not activists*, for a shutdown.  The Reps learned that the hard way in the past, having paid too much attention to your PoV.

Comment: @JonathanReez [Not what CBO says:](https://www.cbo.gov/publication/57444).   *The IRS’s ROIs ramp up over three years as staff become trained and fully productive, arrive at the peak level, and then stay there. In recent years, peak ROIs have ranged from 5 to 9. That is, a **$1 increase in spending on the IRS’s enforcement activities results in $5 to $9 of increased revenues**.*  And you ask enough economic Qs here to know about *diminishing returns*  : no one would believe infinite spending returns infinite revenue, but US is **nowhere** near that point.

Comment: *no one would believe infinite spending returns infinite revenue, but US is nowhere near that point* => again, I don't think that's a seal-and-shut conclusion. Even the original math behind the $5-9/dollar is not necessarily accurate, as the CBO isn't infallible.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The next paragraph is also worth noting, though: "CBO adjusts the ROIs so that they better reflect the marginal return on additional spending. First, CBO expects the IRS to prioritize the enforcement activities that it thinks will have the highest average return; additional enforcement spending would therefore have lower returns than previous spending."

Comment: Downvoted because, frankly, all the discussion of which side looks strong or weak, smart or dumb, etc., is *completely irrelevant* to the question that was asked (why did one particular group of Democrats vote against advancing the bill).

Answer (score -4):

I can't answer specifically for those particular Democrats, but from listening to progressives, interviews on the PBS News Hour and so on, over the past few weeks I can give a general Democratic position, which is: there's no reason to negotiate. Republicans are threatening to shut down the government unless they get stuff? Biden should call their bluff, and whatever happens, he wins, the country wins and Democrats win. Again, these aren't my opinions -- they're what some Democrats are saying about why they should refuse any kind of deal:

Some background: the Debt Ceiling issue is (or was) regarded as hostage-taking due to a loophole. For decades Congress had budget bills deciding how to spend money, and then as a formality, raised the debt ceiling to pay for it. A decent comparison is paying a credit card bill. The money has been spent, discussions about whether $1,200 Taylor Swift tickets are worth it have been had. The time to complain was when you spent the money and when you spend it next. Plus, you have to pay the bill eventually. Paying late is just wasting money.

On to reasons: back with Clinton the Republicans did this same thing, and the Democrats never made a deal, and the government was actually shut down -- the thing we're so worried about happening now has already happened once before. People felt the pain and Republicans got blamed for it. So why not let the Republicans shoot themselves in the foot again? That wasn't the same thing -- not passing a Continuing Resolution vs. not raising the Debt Ceiling, but I've been hearing Democrats compare them as being pretty much the same thing.

Next, morally (for lack of a better word), a serious country should never be having this debate. It makes us look like idiots shutting down every few years, wastes a bunch of money when we re-open, and makes countries trying to do business with us think China might be a better partner. The best way to stop this nonsense from happening every few years is for the President to say we're not having that discussion.

Next, it's terrible negotiation. The Republicans are asking for budget stuff. Well, in a real budget deal the Democrats have the President and the Senate. The deal should be in their favor. But this deal is 100% in the Republicans' favor. It's not as if the Republicans ran on a platform "shut down America -- no Social Security, medicare, veteran's care... ". They want to raise the debt ceiling, too.

And then practically, the shut-down can be avoided. Just like Reagan, Biden can find the money for a while. Then he can go with the "full faith and credit shall not be questioned" to say he's constitutionally required to pretend the debt ceiling has been raised. He can go the $1,000,000,000,000 coin route. Once Americans feel the effects of a shutdown, far-out things start to seem like good ideas (progressives are actually angry that Biden ruled this stuff out, but he can still do them).

Comment: "On to reasons: back with Clinton the Republicans did this same thing, and the Democrats never made a deal, and the government was actually shut down -- the thing we're so worried about happening now has already happened once before." The shutdown in the Clinton term was because of not reaching a budget deal, not the debt ceiling.

Comment: -1: we've never not raised the debt ceiling in time. They came close under obama, but the budget standoff w/Clinton is apples to oranges. The risk here is not a shutdown, it's a lost of investor confidence.

Comment: -1 for the $1,000,000,000,000 coin. For the rest, can't say I agree with it, but everyone's entitled to their opinion. But that coin is pure gimmick and mentioning it in a serious manner makes for a non-serious answer, IMHO.  Remember Truss The Brief?  Markets don't particularly like silly shenanigans indicating bad faith.

Comment: @dandavis The discussion during the Clinton/Gingrich situation was also about a loss of confidence, very similar to the one now. The US was even downgraded slightly as a result. But the point is, Democrats, right-or-wrong, can point to that and say "we come out ahead".

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I'm just reporting the facts. Paul Krugman, a long-time well-known Democratic economist, says the coin is fine. I think the idea is that the Debt Ceiling is already a gimmick, so ignoring it with other gimmicks is fine.

Comment: @OwenReynolds In any issue of importance, with any level of subjectivity you will have proponents and opponents.  As you say, *Democratic* economist (I am sure the opinions of *Republican* economists are equally above reproach and untainted by affiliation). See [Pros and Cons](https://theweek.com/us/1023169/the-pros-and-cons-of-the-trillion-dollar-coin)  : pros - the US *doesn't* default, cons - *potentially* everything else.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The opinions of Republican economists don't matter _for this question_ since OP is asking what _Democratic opinions_ are. I'm seeing that you wrote an answer with inches of personal commentary -- I assume you feel strongly about this issue and let it get to you -- but you know that StackExchange just answers the question (or Frame Challenges).

Comment: You're kidding about *my inches of commentary* part, right?  That's really the pot calling the kettle after all your talk of brinkmanship.  And I only DVed because your $1T coin, which *you* present as an alternative.  My point is any party will find experts testifying that their way is good, so appealing to the authority of a Nobel laureate *affiliated to the Dems* does little to convince Joe Average of the common sense of a $1T coin.  Or economists either.

Comment: The government shutting down which has happened after the Clinton years as well is not the same thing as not paying our debts.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Yeah, not a lot of people outside of the far left take Paul Krugman very seriously. This is the same guy who predicted that the Internet would end up having no more economic impact than the fax machine and who also predicted, on the election night, that the stock market "might never recover" from Trump being elected (of course, in the real world, the DJIA gapped up hundreds of points at market open, had one of its largest two-day point gains in history, and ended up being up around 70% by the end of his term... and I say that as someone who voted against him.)

Comment: @JoeW But I hope you understand that this isn't about your or my opinions. I'm hearing Democrats and progressive talkers express "we came out ahead not making a deal last time, and this is pretty much the same thing". OP apparently hasn't, so asked, and I'm just typing out what I've heard.

Comment: It isn't a matter of opinion that the government has shutdown multiple times since the Clinton years as there was a full shutdown during the Obama years and 2 shutdowns (1 full and one partial) during the Trump years. That is also ignoring the fact that we can still pay our debts during a government shutdown but we can't pay all our debts if we hit the debt ceiling.  And I made no comments about who did or didn't come out ahead.

Comment: @JoeW I know you're trying to help but people get exciting about wanting to debate and jump in before reading the whole Q. In this case, the Q was asking for known Democratic reasons to vote no and in the 1st para I said I was just passing those along. You blew past that, but so did 6 other people, and I should have known better. I added some extra text there to clarify.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Ah, you think these my opinions. I clarified the first para to clarify they aren't. You know how we get Q's asking "what are the stated reasons for X?" and the answers are just "here's what they said?" I see this Q as a cousin -- "what are Progressive Democrats reasons to vote no", well, here's what they said.

Comment: You are answering a question about shutting down the government which is not remotely close to the same thing as the debt ceiling. We have shut down the government many times in the past but we have never before hit the debt ceiling.